# Create Batch File to Undo Windows 10 New Default Printer Behavior

Tags: registry, windows-10, printers

Yesterday I was made aware of a disruptive update that Microsoft released. With one of the Windows 10 updates, Microsoft made it so that your default printer dynamically changes to whatever was the last printer you used.

While I could understand how this could be useful in many situations, there are also many situations in which it will be significantly problematic. An example is if someone printed a small label on a dedicated label printer and then went to print out a 8.5" x 11" report without selecting the printer. The result would be a lot of wasted labels. For my particular situation, this will unfortunately be a rather common experience.

For this reason, I need to find a way to quickly and easily disable this new "feature". I see that there is an option by going to Settings -> Devices -> Printers and Scanners. For my purpose, though, I need something that can be automated. I have a couple hundred computers that I will need to perform this change on.

Answer (score 3):

I looked around a good bit, but was unable to find the complete answer elsewhere and so decided to answer my own question.

The answer is to put a REG ADD command in a batch file. The command is:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" /v "LegacyDefaultPrinterMode" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

Steps:

1. Create a text file and paste the above in it.
2. Change the file's extension to .bat.
3. Double-click the file to run it.